# How would I say 'what ...' in Mandarin

Tags: translation, mandarin, word-requests, phrase-request

I think the French ce qui/que says it better. This is what I mean:

> I do what I want. (Je fais ce que je veux, in French)

How would the 'what' be translated?

Comment: Probably use "this" or "that" as a filler in Chinese. Like: 我做这个我想做的, 我想做那个我想做的.

Comment: I see. Is it optional?

Comment: Yes, it is optional, chinese hate wordy sentences. Or the translation can go like this: 我做我想做的(事)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say 我做我想做的. Here I use 我想做的 to represent things that I want to do. Since I use I use 我做, I use 做 after 想。 If I want to say that I drink what I want. I would say 我喝我想喝的。 Here I use 我喝 so I use 喝 after 想 too.

If you want to simplify it, you can say 我做我想要的(I do what I want).

Comment: So 的 nominalises 我想做 and 我想喝? Oh yeah, I never considered that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something somehow bad:

我为所欲为。

I always think of 所 as 'thatwhich' but it may be 'this' or 'what'

Comment: Interesting translation, I wonder how it compares to the more "direct" translation above